# Use Slider value to change Button's content

Tags: c#, wpf, button, slider

I have a series of Paths I want displayed one-by-one in a specific order as the content of a button when the value of a slider changes. The value of the slider should determine which Path is displayed.

I have defined my Paths in a Resource Dictionary and both the Button and Slider have Styles assigned to them as well.

I'm relatively new to xml and WPF and I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I have searched for over an hour now and I believe I need some kind of binding or trigger, but I can't find what I'm looking for. Please help! :)

Edit: I believe I'm looking for a DataTemplate or DataTrigger, but I need some guidance as of how to implement that into my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <col:ArrayList x:Key="al">
      <Path Data="M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100" Fill="Black"/>
      <Path Data="M 0,0 L 100,300"  Fill="Black" Stroke="Black"/>
    </col:ArrayList>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lb}"/>
    <ListBox Name="lb" ItemsSource="{StaticResource al}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Value, ElementName=sl}" Visibility="Collapsed">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate/>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Name="sl" SmallChange="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="true" />
  </StackPanel> 
</Grid>
```

with col namespace being: `xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: so, did this answer help you?

Comment: I suppose to use it with more than 2 paths, I just add paths in the array and increase the slider's maximum?